# Issue in Wpf Inverted DataGrid Row, Column Resize

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF, Here I am trying `DataGrid` with inversion, but my problem is whenever I try to resize the columns and rows it's not resized properly because it was inverted now the rows are resize with vertical and columns are in horizontal.

How can I get it to look and behave like in the uninverted DataGrid?

Code here:

```
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style  TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
<DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
```

Comment: Do you mean transpose with inversion?

Comment: Yes and i wanna resize the row in horizontal instead of vertical. is that possible?